# How to pass value from java to PHP?

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I am trying to pass a value from java class to PHP file on the server to test this value and reply to java. The problem it returns null value.

## Java Code

```
package phpJava;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class phpbirgde {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            String erg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("2+3");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://localhost//test.php?test="+erg).openStream()));
                    String b = br.readLine();
                    System.out.println(b); // print the string b
                    if(b.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                        System.out.println("It is true");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("False");
                    }

            } catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("error");
            }
}

    }
```

## PHP Code

```
 <?php
 $test = $_GET['test'];
 if($test =="5"){
 echo "true";
 }
 else {
 echo "false";
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly returns null?

Comment: I have fixed the problem, thanks. It was returning a space to java. This space comes from the 'HTML' before the '<?php'  tag because in my php file it was a space before the '<?php'  tag and I fixed it. @k5_

Answer (score 2):

It is by [contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()):

> `public String readLine() throws IOException`
>
> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.
>
> **Returns**:
>
> A String containing the contents of the line, not including
>   any line-termination characters, **or null if the end of the stream has
>   been reached**

In your case the php script just outputs `true` string (without `\n`) into the output stream and closes the connection.

So, add the `\n` (`echo "true\n";`) on PHP side, or use another method to read the response from Java side.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I have put a space before the php tag in PHP file and it was returning the space only.
Now this code works perfectly.

Comment: It it is work as is, than I almost sure your have an extra "End-of-line" character at the end of your php file, after the `?>`. Try to remove it and it will break again, because the `end-of-line` character is mandatory for `readLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) classes

```
String loc = "http://localhost//test.php?test="+erg;
URL url = new URL(loc);
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream i = con.getInputStream();
```

Otherwise, your PHP looks OK.